# Is there an option to read SMS in iOS devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, sms, user-permissions

I'm currently developing a budget tracker app in React Native that extracts expenditure information from transactional messages.

I've successfully implemented the message reading functionality on Android using the react-native-get-sms-android package. However, I'm facing challenges in finding a similar solution for iOS as Apple does not allow us to read user messages.

Are there alternative approaches or suggestions to make this functionality work seamlessly on both platforms?

I am using React native to Build my app.

I've investigated various possibilities, but I haven't been able to discover a viable solution so far.

Comment: There is no such capability.  It is a privacy risk.

Comment: @Paulw11 any option to get permission ?

Comment: No. Apps do not have access to messages. iOS is a privacy first platform

Answer (score 0):

There is an property named [textContentType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#textcontenttype-ios) set it’s value to oneTimeCode (OTP).

Further [information](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)

Comment: They don't want OTP. They want text messages that some credit card companies send with transaction details. It isn't going to happen on ios